# Create private folders for certain users only - Active Directory Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I would like to create an admin folder on the server which only certain users have read/write access to.  Other users should not be able to see it at all.  We have windows server 2008 and user accounts are all created in active directory.

Can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Are the users accessing the folders via a share?

If so, you can achieve this with Abe (Access-based Enumeration). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(WS.10).aspx